# vtiger7 master-details module

Tags: master-detail, vtigercrm

Hello I need to create a new module in vtger 7 that will be used to register some information similar as an Invoice but without product's price.
This module will have a master block when you can choose the customer, date ect... and a details sections when you have multiple rows and the user can select product, description and quantity...

I already created the "master" module but I don't know how create the rows and attach to the main module...

Someone can suggest some docs or example, please ?

Best regards

Comment: You can use Purchase Orders or Sales Orders module, if you are not using them.

Comment: I have to create a new module I can't use use Sales Order or Purchase because they are already used. Can I duplicate an existing module ?